# Spring Boot @ControllerAdvice / @Valid

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, error-handling, controller-advice

I am working on sample demo application for Exception Handling in Spring Boot.I am trying Exception Handling With @ControllerAdvice.

I would like to handle exception thrown by validator. It handles other exceptions but not MethodArgumentNotValidException.

For more details following are the classes I am working on:

**Query.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class Query implements Serializable{
    @Size(min = 7, max = 24, message = "Size must be between 7 and 24")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", Invalid characters")
    private String number;

    @Size(max = 2, message = "Size must be between 0 and 2")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", message="Invalid characters")
    private String language;
}
```

**ErrorResponse.java**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class ErrorResponse 
{

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    private HttpStatus status;

    private int code;

    private String error;

    private String exception;

    private String message;

    private String path;

    private List<String> errors;

}
```

*CustomExceptionHandler.java*

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","rawtypes"})
@ControllerAdvice
@Component("error")
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFoundError(NotFoundException ex, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(InternalServerException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleInternelServorError(InternalServerException ex, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> errorList = ex
                .getBindingResult()
                .getFieldErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(fieldError -> fieldError.getDefaultMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getData(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            @Valid @ApiParam(value = "MANDATORY. The number") @PathVariable(value = "number", required = true) final String partNumber,
            @Valid @ApiParam(value = "OPTIONAL. The language") @RequestParam(value = "language", required = false) final String languageKey) {
.............
}
```

Comment: Try to annotate handleMethodArgumentNotValid method with @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException .class) and see what happens?

Comment: you're not handling this MethodArgumentNotValidException ...

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and here's how I solved it:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {   
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // handle validation exception here
    }
}
```

**Note**: if you have multiple classes that extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and are all `@ControllerAdvice`, you may have some trouble getting this overidden function to be executed. I had to have this overidden in a base class for all my exception handlers in order for it to finally be used. I may, in the future, put all my exception handlers into one class to avoid this.

> source:
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0hwXOeMdUM

Answer (score 0):

You create `List<String> errorList` but never use it and return just empty `ErrorResponse`

Answer (score 0):

You have not a handler for `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. Adding this:

```java
    ...
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public void methodArgumentNotValidException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }
    ...
```

To your `CustomExceptionHandler` should work.